# StartActivity Not working Monogame

Tags: android, web, xamarin, monogame

I'm trying to open a webpage in my Monogame app, but it is saying "The name 'StartActivity' does not exist in the current context"

My code is :

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("https://www.google.com/");
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
StartActivity (launchBrowser);
```

And i am currently calling:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android .Content .Res ;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call startActivity with a valid context if calling outside a class that does not inherit from Context. Do it this way:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Where `context` is the context from which you are calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: Please add some more code where you are calling your activity from It is difficult to answer or find the problem without looking at your entire code.